# Need an event to hook up to for Excel CubeValue refresh

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, events

Is there a VBA event I can hook into for cubevalue refresh or update?  I'm trying to reconfigure a custom chart axis when the value is returned.  I've tried the chart calculate but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find was forcing the async function to complete at the application level:

```
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```